# How to place an array of struct at specific location in RAM such as backup RAM in STM32F4 MCUs?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I am trying to store an array in the backup RAM on STM32F4 MCUs, so the content can survive system power cycle such as reboot caused by watchdog.

```
typedef struct {
  //
} Foo;

Foo foos[40];
```

Is there a way to make sure foos points to the start of backup RAM(BKPSRAM_BASE) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your linker script and add section which will be in your backup RAM.

to memory segments:

```
MEMORY
{
    /* other segments */
    BKPRAM (rw)       : ORIGIN = 0x40024000, LENGTH = 4k
}
```

Add section

```
  .bkpram :
  {
    _BKPRAM_START = .;
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.bkpram)) 
    _BKPRAM_END = .;
  } >BKPRAM
```

Then:

```
__attribute__((section(".bkpram"))) Foo foos[40];
```

But remember that access to this SRAM has to be enabled first.

Comment: In backup RAM as he wants. And it will start at the beginning of bachup RAM. It will also make sure that other data will not overlap and not overflow backup ram

Comment: Because it is the only variable in this section. if you want to make sure add subsections.